# How do you turn off Bluetooth on startup using MacBook Air and macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos

Every time I turn on my laptop (from a completely off state) the Bluetooth is on by default. How can I prevent it from turning on at startup and then only turn it on (manually) when I want to connect any Bluetooth devices like mouse and keyboard?

Answer (score 6):

If you're still looking for solutions to this, you could try this Terminal command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist ControllerPowerState 0
```

Source: [Apple Support Communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22250717#message22250717)